# How to stop removing element in editable table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When editing table cells the user can select the entire cell and delete the contents, so removed the handlers to stretch the size of the cell (UI-resizable). 
How to stop the destruction of these supporting elements?

In this example .ui-resizable-handle in each cell. Their removal must be prevented

```
<table>
<caption>table title</caption>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>header</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="ui-resizable">
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ui-resizable">
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ui-resizable">
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I tried something like this, but it not working

```
 $('.ui-resizable-handle').on('remove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be  no event will be trigger when a dom element removed, if you want to prevent the removal, just detect key event, and use `e.preventDefault()` when user press `backspace` or `delete`.

```
$('.ui-resizable-handle').on('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 46 || event.keyCode === 8){// 'delete' or 'backspace'
       if($(this).text().length === 0){ //no text in cell
           event.preventDefault();
           return false;
       }
    }

 });
```